# I need to get the list of users who have previously been sent message (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making an instant messaging web page, I have assembled the entire database and made 100% of the front-end of the entire page, I only have to do the start menu ...
So in the start menu I just want to show users that ** a message has been sent to before **, I haven't managed to do this, and right now I'm showing a list of ** all registered users ** .. Something like the following is what I am showing

```
PROFILE PHOTO 1 - User Nº1 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 2 - User Nº2 - No messages have been sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 3 - User Nº3 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 4 - User Nº4 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
```

When what I want to show is something like the following:

```
PROFILE PHOTO 1 - User Nº1 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 3 - User Nº3 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 4 - User Nº4 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
```

Currently the design of my table is as follows:

```
> messages
msg_id | incoming_msg_id | incoming_msg_id | outgoing_msg_id | msg
```

```
> users
user_id | unique_id | fname | lname | email | password | img | status
```

*Clarification, the incoming_msg_id field is the ID of the user who receives the message, and the outgoing_msg_id is the one that sends it, which in this case matches the user_id field of the `users` table.*

Currently my code is the following, which, as I have told you, shows what I leave below.

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once "config.php";
    $outgoing_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT unique_id = {$outgoing_id} ORDER BY user_id DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $output = "";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        $output .= "No users are available to chat";
    }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        include_once "data.php";
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

```
PROFILE PHOTO 1 - User Nº1 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 2 - User Nº2 - No messages have been sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 3 - User Nº3 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
PROFILE PHOTO 4 - User Nº4 - Last message sent - Status (Offline / Online)
```

Finally I leave you two real and current photos of my boards:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTqqn.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/25I40.png

---

> EDITED

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to get field user_id in  table (messages).
Later you can join this table and write select  like :

```
select * from users usr
join messages msg on msg.user_id = usr.user_id
where msg.incoming_msg_id is not null
```

It will show later all users who sended message.

@UPDATE

If you said the field **outgoing_msg_id** is the user id  there select will be like this:

```
select DISTINCT usr.user_id,usr.fname,usr.lname from users usr
join messages msg on msg.outgoing_msg_id = usr.user_id
```

This select will show all users who sended message.

@EDIT 3

```
So your php code should be like :

<?php
    session_start();
    include_once "config.php";
    $outgoing_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT unique_id = {$outgoing_id} and unique_id in (select outgoing_msg_id from messages)  ORDER BY user_id DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $output = "";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        $output .= "No users are available to chat";
    }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        include_once "data.php";
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in `route`

Comment: Firstly you need to edit table messages , and add there new field : user_id -> that will be the same as user_id in users table.

Comment: The user_id of what of the two users?

Comment: Don't think so , you need to check that i don't know yours database scheme. 
But judging by the field name, it doesn't seem to be the id of the user who sent the message. IF you are sure it is id of users who send the message i can edit my answear and write correct select

Comment: Now I have another problem, for each message and each user who has sent a message is showing me the field Example:

User 1 - LastMsg - ID
 //
User 1 - LastMsg - ID
 //
User 2 - LastMsg - ID
 //
User 1 - LastMsg - ID

Comment: And I only need to obtain the user, not each message

Comment: edited answear , check that and remember to mark as resolved :)

Comment: so you need to use DISTINCT , edited second sql . If you still have problem please attach screenshoot with database and what you write in select code

Comment: I do not know if you understand me, I am making a messaging application, and I only want to obtain and display on the home page the users who have already received a message before

Comment: Added screenshots

Comment: Edited answear , you need something like this. This select should show you user 2 and user 3. Based on your screenshoots ( depends who you are logged in now )  . If you are logged in with user 2  there result will show only user 3. Based on your screenshoot.

Comment: Oh nice, now it works! and how could I also show the user if I have sent him a message?

Comment: This is another question. Please validate the answer, create a new ASK, give the link in the comment and I will try to help there.

Comment: Doesn't work, the query only shows me the users who have receive a message from anyone to anyone, but i need to show only the users who receive a message directly

Comment: corrected with: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT unique_id = {$outgoing_id} and unique_id in (select outgoing_msg_id from messages WHERE incoming_msg_id={$outgoing_id})  ORDER BY user_id DESC`

Comment: exacly you did very well :)

Comment: Also, I don't know if I should create a new ask for only what I said before, because is related to this

Comment: So if you can help me here it would  be nice!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68572597/sql-obtain-users-who-have-received-o-send-a-messages-update