# SQL obtain users who have received o send a messages (UPDATE)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE NOT unique_id = {$outgoing_id} 
  and unique_id in (select outgoing_msg_id 
                    from messages 
                    WHERE incoming_msg_id={$outgoing_id})  
                    ORDER BY user_id DESC);
```

More info about the DB and tables in: [I need to get the list of users who have previously been sent message (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68560997) (This is another question, but about the same)

Comment: what you want to show exacly ? I dont understand question

Comment: And what is your question? PS. Do you really think that somebody will jump from Q to Q for to solve ***your*** problem? Post needed data completely. PPS. ORDER BY in the subquery makes no sense.

Comment: You need to select users who receiveed message from you?

Comment: In the other post I explain better

Comment: But I have put it in another post because one of the users who answer say me that i should create other post

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED WITH:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT unique_id = "337244286" and unique_id in (
SELECT outgoing_msg_id FROm messages WHERE incoming_msg_id="337244286") 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT unique_id = "337244286" and unique_id in (select incoming_msg_id from messages WHERE outgoing_msg_id="337244286")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it with user id 1 as an example:

```sql
SELECT 
  first_name 
FROM 
  users 
  LEFT JOIN messages received_messages ON received_messages.from_id = 1 
  AND received_messages.to_id = users.id 
  LEFT JOIN messages sent_messages ON sent_messages.from_id = users.id 
  AND sent_messages.to_id = 1 
WHERE 
  received_messages.id IS NOT NULL 
  OR sent_messages.id IS NOT NULL
```